# Is it possible to control the alpha of status bar on iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

It is possible to animate the alpha with a duration like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.navController setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}];
```

But would it be possible through CoreAnimation and UIKit to control the alpha with display link or gestures as a driver instead? I'm talking about brief moments while doing a gesture driver transition from one controller to another.

Sometimes a plain animateWithDuration just isn't what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Since the code below works, you can change the alpha at will.

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
        navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = CGFloat(sender.value)
    }
}
```

If the question is about animating during a transition, and the timing is the issue, you then want to control that transition with the [UIPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPresentationController_class/), which provides timing information.

Comment: This question appears to be about the status bar in particular, not about the navigation bar below it.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon: That escaped me, since in the nav controller was covering the status bar.